android emulator can't connect to laravel herd site
I'm using Laravel Herd to host my local API and I'm trying to connect to it using the Android Studio emulator. However, I keep encountering the following error: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "dt_back.test": No address associated with hostname

I've already tried creating a network configuration:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">dt_back.test</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>


And I've imported it into the manifest:
<application
        android:name=".DatingApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.DT_APP_COMPOSE"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. What could be causing this problem and how can I resolve it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633577/android-cannot-resolve-hostname-on-internal-network-but-i-cant-use-ip-address

Check network settings of the device. If Privacy DNS is activated then it uses Google DNS server for resulting which of course doesn't know anything about your dt_back.test domain.

device has no Privacy DNS. It has its default settings
